# YUV live video streaming using Flask

Tags: python, flask, live-streaming, yuv

I'm currently working on a project involving a small robotic car using the Raspberry Pi. In order to use the picamera efficiently (both for image processing and a live webstream), I would like to use the YUV420 format (which is supported by picamera). This allows me to directly use the Y values for image processing and leaving any further conversion to the client.

Is it possible to quickly stream this array (with a Python generator) through a Flask Response object (as shown here with JPEG: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask)? If so, I know I can convert the YUV data to RGB in JavaScript and then draw it to a canvas, but how do I access the YUV stream one frame at a time?

If there are any other, more efficient solutions (while sticking to Flask), I'd like to hear about them too. The Flask Response with Python generator just worked like a charm for a JPEG webstream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the `picamera` documentation](https://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/recipes1.html#capturing-to-a-stream) and [the blog post you've linked](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask), you could create a multipart response consisting of a stream of YUV420 frames captured from the camera with code like this:

```
def gen():
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
      camera.start_preview()
      # Camera warm-up time
      time.sleep(2)

      while True:
        stream = io.BytesIO()
        camera.capture(stream, 'yuv')
        yield stream.getvalue()
        #perhaps add a time.sleep() here to enforce a constant framerate?
```

However, that doesn't address the client-side.  Because you want to use the image data in JavaScript, rather than just displaying it in an `<img>` tag, you'd need to fetch it from JavaScript with XMLHTTPRequest, and XMLHTTPRequest doesn't support multipart responses (specifically, Firefox [used to and no longer does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#multipart)).

The better approach would be to use [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API), since then it would be easy to [open a WebSocket connection from JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications), read each frame in turn (each frame being sent in its own WebSocket message), and perform the necessary image processing.  But what about the server-side?  [`Flask-Sockets`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-sockets) looks like it will do the trick, and then sending the stream of frames would look something like this:

```
@sockets.route('/stream')
def stream_socket(ws):
    with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
      camera.start_preview()
      # Camera warm-up time
      time.sleep(2)

      while not ws.closed:
        stream = io.BytesIO()
        camera.capture(stream, 'yuv')
        ws.send(stream.getvalue())
        #perhaps add a time.sleep() here to enforce a constant framerate?
```

Comment: Is it even possible to just display it in an `<img>` tag, without any conversion in JavaScript (while keeping the yuv format)? I will look into the WebSocket solution, thanks.

Comment: If you want to render the image in an `<img>` tag, it'll need to be in a format the browser understands (PNG, JPEG, etc.), so you wouldn't be able to use YUV420 for that.  However, `picamera` can easily return JPEG-encoded images—just change `'yuv'` to `'jpeg'` in the first example.